# Gazebo-Turtlebot turning by itself, cmd_vel topic is zero

Tags: navigation, gazebo, rviz, turtlebot

I am using Noetic.I am simulating a multirobot navigation system with 4 turtlebots, I am using the navigation stack and Rviz. The problems begin when the goals of robots are reached. Sometimes one or more turtlebot seems to turn clockwise by itself, so the amcl gets confused by /scan topic. I don't know why this happens, I am monitoring the cmd_vel topic, but zero velocities are published. Only the move base node subscribes to this topic.
In the following pic the yellow arrow is the goal I published to the move base node, the red arrow matched the yellow arrow, but it started drifting.
[image: yellow arrow is the goal I published to the move base node, the red arrow matched the yellow arrow, but it started drifting]

The source code link for [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rtobE2PwfSEKE4ESGT7I2WngxcNCtVnI)
I use the main4.launch and the navigation4.launch.
I have also created a node that publishes in cmd_vel zero values, but it is still turning.
There is also a video showing the turtlebot turning, and some screenshots.

Monitor of the odom when stopped [image]

[image]
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the peak yaw velocity (twist.angular.z) reported on the robot's odom topic when it is in this condition? Monitor for about a minute or so.

Comment: When the robot that starts spinning it starts to, rise, usually it is around 0.0002. I uploaded a photo in the question description.

Comment: When i use roswtf, these are the errors I get, i don't think they have something to do with this problem                                                                                                                    ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /move_base1->/move_base1 (/move_base1/local_costmap/footprint)
* /move_base1->/move_base1 (/move_base1/global_costmap/footprint)
... for every movebase node

Comment: A yaw velocity of 0.10 rad/sec is extremely large for an idle robot. Please add your map .yaml file and your .world files to google drive. In gazebo, what `max_step_size` is being used?

Comment: I did upload them, .wolrd file is in the world file, and the .yaml is in the maps file. I suppose max_step_size is the default, I haven't changed it, I usually don't use the gazebo gui.

Comment: I do not see the files `thesis_map.world` or `thesis_map_enlarged.yaml`.

Comment: sorry, these files are in the worlds folder and the maps folder

Comment: You apply an offset in your map .yaml file. Are you sure that the gazebo x,y,z coordinates and the map x,y,z coordinates are perfectly aligned?

Comment: This must be an old version. I uploaded the yaml file I just used in my simulation, and checked right now. For me, it works good, and it is aligned. I uploaded a video showing step by step what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the problem was in the .world file. I started adding the extra parameters that were in the turtlebot3_world.world file to mine, and the issue solved. To be specific, the new world file is:

```
<!-- A global light source -->
<include>
  <uri>model://sun</uri>
</include>

<!-- A ground plane -->
<include>
  <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
</include>

<physics type="ode">
  <real_time_update_rate>10000.0</real_time_update_rate> <!--100 is default-->
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <ode>
    <solver>
      <type>quick</type>
      <iters>150</iters>
      <precon_iters>0</precon_iters>
      <sor>1.400000</sor>
      <use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>1</use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>
    </solver>
    <constraints>
      <cfm>0.00001</cfm>
      <erp>0.2</erp>
      <contact_max_correcting_vel>2000.000000</contact_max_correcting_vel>
      <contact_surface_layer>0.01000</contact_surface_layer>
    </constraints>
  </ode>
</physics>

<!-- Load world -->
<include>
  <uri>model://thesis_map_enlarged</uri>
  <name>thesis_map_enlarged</name>
  <pose>0.0 0.0 -2.1 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>

<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
  <shadows>true</shadows>
</scene>

<gui fullscreen='0'>
  <camera name='user_camera'>
    <pose>0.8 0.0 12.0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
    <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
  </camera>
</gui>
```